# Python, check if two strings is equal character by character

Tags: python

```
def check_equal(a, b):
if len(a) > len(b):
    for i in range(0, len(a), 1):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
else:
    for i in range(0, len(b), 1):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

I can't get it to compare more than the first characters of a and b. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: because you are returning `True/False` after the first character itself.

Comment: Because you `return` on the very first iteration.

Comment: Unindent your `else: return True` clause by 1 level and remove the `else`.  You're close, just short-circuiting your result

Comment: I don't understand your outermost `if/else`.  If the two lengths are unequal, that means the strings are unequal.

Comment: `return` will cause the function to end and return either the `True` or `False` which you are returning

Comment: String comparisons are already performed character by character; you are just re-implementing `a == b`. (Note that `a[i]` and `b[i]` are also `str` objects of length one, not a separate character type as in many languages, so your two comparisons already rely on the built-in string comparison.)

Comment: Use : return a==b

Comment: @user3483203 FWIW I think you can just leave the `else`

Answer (score 2):

Here is your own code with a slight modification. Hope you find it useful. Here if the strings are of unequal length, it makes no sense to compare them. In this case, you print the message and simply return. Otherwise, you compare character wise and if any of the characters is different, you `return False` else you continue to check the next character. Once all the characters are found equal, you print that the strings are equal.

```
def check_equal(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        print ("String lengths not equal")
        return
    else:
        for i in range(len(b)):
            if a[i] != b[i]:
                return False

    print ("Strings are equal and same")
```

---

```
check_equal("Donald", "Donald") 
# Strings are equal and same  

check_equal("Donald", "Trump")    
# String lengths not equal
```

Comment: The only quibble I have with this solution is that it only checks the lengths one way. Might it be better to do `if len(a) != len(b):`, in case the second string is the longer one

Comment: @khelwood: I edited my solution. Kindly revoke your downvote if applicable.

Comment: @G.Anderson: I edited my solution. Kindly revoke your downvote if applicable.

Comment: @Austin: Thanks for the comment. I edited the if condition to `!=`

Comment: Did not downvote, as the solution was in line with the OP's original solution

Comment: @G.Anderson: Thanks :)